# How to iterate throught C++ sets in Cython?

Tags: c++, python-2.7, cython

I am optimizing python code with Cython. A set in C++ is storing all my results, and I do not know how to access the data to move it into a Python object. The structure must be a set. I cannot change it to a vector, list, etc.

I know how to do this in Python and C++, but not in Cython. How are iterators retrieved in Cython? I get STL containers via  libcpp.STLContainer as in

> from libcpp.vector cimport vector

But, I don't know how iterators work in Cython. What do I need to import? And, is there any change in syntax for using iterators compared to how they work in C++?

Comment: Doesn't the C++ class have its own iterator?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to invoke it. I tried several things and none worked. The set class file itself defines iterator within the class definition, but I don't know how to access it.

Comment: Is this doc section of any use: http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#standard-library

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Cython should automatically convert a c++ set to a python set when needed, however if you really *do* need to use iterators on the c++ object you can do that as well.

If we make a very simple example where we construct a set in c++

**libset.cc**

```
#include <set>

std::set<int> make_set()
{
    return {1,2,3,4};
}
```

**libset.h**

```
#include <set>

std::set<int> make_set();
```

We can then write the cython wrapper for this code as, where I've given an example of how to iterate through the set in a nice pythonic way (which uses the c++ iterators in the background) and an example of how to do it directly with iterators.

**pyset.pyx**

```
from libcpp.set cimport set
from cython.operator cimport dereference as deref, preincrement as inc

cdef extern from "libset.h":
    cdef set[int] _make_set "make_set"()

def make_set():
    cdef set[int] cpp_set = _make_set()

    for i in cpp_set: #Iterate through the set as a c++ set
        print i

    #Iterate through the set using c++ iterators.
    cdef set[int].iterator it = cpp_set.begin()
    while it != cpp_set.end():
        print deref(it)
        inc(it)

    return cpp_set    #Automatically convert the c++ set into a python set
```

This can then be compiled with a simple setup.py

**setup.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup( ext_modules = cythonize(Extension(
            "pyset",
            sources=["pyset.pyx", "libset.cc"],
            extra_compile_args=["-std=c++11"],
            language="c++"
     )))
```

Answer (score 3):

Very nice answer by Simon. I had to do this for a C++ map to python dict. Here's my rough cython code for the map case:

```
from libcpp.map cimport map

# code here for _make_map() etc.

def get_map():
    '''
    get_map()
    Example of cython interacting with C++ map.

    :returns: Converts C++ map<int, int> to python dict and returns the dict
    :rtype: dict
    '''
    cdef map[int, int] cpp_map = _make_map()

    pymap = {}
    for it in cpp_map: #Iterate through the c++ map
        pymap[it.first] = it.second

    return pymap
```